# Scientific Logic for not praying at Zawal (noon) time

Tags: prayer-timings, scientific-proof

I have read somewhere that at noon time when sun is exactly at up and making a right angle with earth some dangerous rays emit from earth that's why it is forbidden to pray at that time. But i could find any scientific logic behind that. Can any one explain in detail ?

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum and Welcome to Islam.SE. Why do you want the scientific reason for that?

Comment: @Muslim First to convince myself then to convince others.

Comment: prayers aren't allowed at that tym but i doubt the truth behind radiation . Even if you are standing, that radiation could affect you.

Comment: Have you considered skeptics.se?

Answer (score 4):

['Uqbah bin 'Amir Al-Juhani said](https://sunnah.com/nasai:2013):

> *There are **three** times at which the **Messenger of Allah forbade us to pray** or to bury our dead: When the sun has risen fully until it is higher, **when it reaches its zenith until it has passed the zenith**, and when the sun starts to set*

Now keeping verse [3:32](http://quranx.com/3.32) in mind, we cannot pray at sharp noon.

I doubt the validity of the scientific logic you quoted, because it is very unlikely that the rays will harm us while we are under the roof of Masjid.

Answer (score -4):

Prayers are not allowed at that time because earth emits such harmfull rays that can cause dangerious deseases like brain hemorrhage.